# Does Noether's theorem also give rise to quantities conserved over space?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, field-theory, noethers-theorem

Noether's theorem gives rise to quantities that are conserved over time. But does it also give rise to quantities that are conserved over space?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In basic Lagrangian mechanics (of the sort that is covered in a sophomore-level classical mechanics class), no it doesn't. The reason is that time plays a special role in the basic Lagrangian theory: it's the only independent parameter, which everything else is expressed as a function of. This is related to the fact that the action is the integral of the Lagrangian over *time*, not space, and that in turn means that the "classical" version of Noether's theorem only works for conservation in time.

However, when you generalize to field theory, the situation changes: in field theory, both the time and space coordinates are considered to be independent parameters, so that everything else is expressed as a function of both time and space. In particular, instead of the classical Lagrangian, you have a Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$, which lets you express the action as a spacetime integral,

$$S = \int \mathcal{L}\mathrm{d}^4x$$

So the field theory version of Noether's theorem doesn't assign any special status to time. Instead of temporal conservation laws ($\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$), it gives you spacetime conservation laws of the form

$$\frac{\partial j^\mu}{\partial x^\mu} = 0$$

You can turn this into a temporal conservation law by integrating the current $j^\mu$ over a spacelike volume (i.e. all of space at a single moment in time):

$$Q = \int_{t=\text{const}} g_{\mu\nu} j^\mu\mathrm{d}x^\nu\quad\to\quad\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$$

but you can just as well turn it into a spatial conservation law by integrating over a spatiotemporal volume:

$$Q = \int_{x=\text{const}} g_{\mu\nu} j^\mu\mathrm{d}x^\nu\quad\to\quad\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0$$

So in this way, yes it is possible to create a spatial conservation law using Noether's theorem.

Comment: You say: "In nonrelativistic classical mechanics, no it doesn't". Why can't you have a Lagrangian density over Galilean space-time with a Euclidean metric and from this derive conserved quantities over space?

Comment: @John: because classical mechanics doesn't use the concept of the Lagrangian density. That's an idea from field theory. Then again, the distinction is pretty artificial... I guess what I wanted to say was that it _isn't_ done that way in classical physics, though you're right that it could be. I'll think of some way to rephrase that.

Comment: The Lagrangian density is used in classical mechanics, such as for an elastic material. You can use v << c for non-relativistic mechanics to simplify the relativistic expressions for the conserved quantities which shows they're equivalently all independent of time.

Comment: OK, well maybe "classical" isn't the right word then. "Particle mechanics" perhaps.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, in a field-theoretic setting. Consider a $3+1$ dimensional flat space-time for simplicity. [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) gives rise to a conservation law of the form

$$d_{\mu} J^{\mu}(x)=0,$$

i.e. the Noether current $J^{\mu}(x)$ is a divergence-less four-current. [We use the symbol $d_{\mu}$ (rather than $\partial_{\mu}$) to stress the fact that the derivative $d_{\mu}$ is a *total* derivative, which involves both implicit differentiation through the field variables $\phi^{\alpha}(x)$, and explicit differentiation wrt. $x^{\mu}$.]

Say we want to consider a quantity $Q$ that is independence of the $x^1$-coordinate. Define the so-called 'charge' $Q=Q(x^1)$ by integrating $J^1(x)$ over the $2+1$ dimensional plane with fixed $x^1$-coordinate $x^1$. Then it is easy to show using a $2+1$ dimensional [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) that

$$d_{1} Q(x^1)=0$$

by imposing pertinent boundary conditions.

The above construction may be vastly generalized to a geometrically covariant framework, where the preferred direction is given by a non-vanishing vector field, which can be time-like, space-like, light-like, or some combination.