# Noether's conserved charges: why are there not "spatially" conserved charges?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, spacetime, conservation-laws, field-theory, noethers-theorem

Noether theorem implies that there is a conserved current $j^\mu$ for every continuous symmetry of the action, i.e. $$\partial_\mu j^\mu=0 $$

to each conserved current we can associate a conserved charge

$$\partial_0j^0+\partial_ij^i=0 $$

integrating

$$ \partial_0\int d^3x\,j^0=-\int d^3x \,\partial_ij^i=0$$ 
by the divergence theorem and assuming that the current is $0$ at infinity

But wait, why do this only with the time component? Why can't I write (not using Einstein's convention) 
$$ \partial_a j^a=-\sum_{k\neq a}\partial_kj^k\\
\partial_a\int dt \,dx_k\,dx_l \,j^a=-\int dt \,dx_k\,dx_l \,(\partial_tj^t +\partial_kj^k+\partial_lj^l)=0$$

with $k,l\neq a$ and where in the last equality I assumed the current is $0$ at infinity and sufficiently far in the future and past?

Is this something true but useless or is there something wrong in supposing the current is $0$ in the past and future (or in some other point of the derivation)? No field theory book or script I've come across mentions it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12094/2451

Comment: thank you! I hadn't caught that, it looks like it's pretty much identical to my question. I gather that it's right, but not very useful. Should I delete this question?